# How to run a bash script from within python and get all the output?

Tags: python, bash, queue, subprocess

This is a direct clarification question to the answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59952928/how-to-execute-a-bash-script-from-within-python-in-a-non-blocking-way-and-allow/59954630) which I thought it worked, but it does not!

I have the following test bash script (`testbash.sh`) which just creates some output and a lot of errors for testing purposes (running on Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.6 (Maipo) and also Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS):

```
export MAX_SEED=2
echo "Start test"
pids=""

for seed in `seq 1 ${MAX_SEED}`
do
  python -c "raise ValueError('test')" &
  pids="${pids} $!"
done
echo "pids: ${pids}"
wait $pids
echo "End test"
```

If I run this script I get the following output:

```
Start test
pids:  68322 68323
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: test
[1]-  Exit 1                  python -c "raise ValueError('test')"
[2]+  Exit 1                  python -c "raise ValueError('test')"
End test
```

That is the expected outcome. That is fine. I want to get errors!

Now here is the python code that is supposed to catch all the output:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import sys
import time
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen, STDOUT
from threading  import Thread

try:
    from queue import Queue, Empty
except ImportError:
    from Queue import Queue, Empty  # python 2.x    

ON_POSIX = 'posix' in sys.builtin_module_names

def enqueue_output(out, queue):
    for line in iter(out.readline, b''):
        queue.put(line.decode('ascii'))
    out.close()

p = Popen(['. testbash.sh'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, bufsize=1, close_fds=ON_POSIX, shell=True)
q = Queue()
t = Thread(target=enqueue_output, args=(p.stdout, q))
t.daemon = True # thread dies with the program
t.start()

# read line without blocking
while t.is_alive():
    #time.sleep(1)
    try:
        line = q.get(timeout=.1)
    except Empty:
        print(line)
        pass
    else:
        # got line
        print(line, end='')

p.wait()
print('returncode = {}'.format(p.returncode))
```

But when I run this code I only get the following output:

```
Start test
pids:  70191 70192
Traceback (most recent call last):
returncode = 0
```

or this output (without the line `End test`):

```
Start test
pids:  10180 10181
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: test
returncode = 0
```

Most of the above output is missing! How can I fix this? Also, I need some way to check if any command in the bash script did not succeed. In the example this is the case, but the errorcode printed out is still 0. I expect an errorcode != 0.

It is not important to immediately get the output. A delay of some seconds is fine. Also if the output order is a bit mixed up this is of no concern. The important thing is to get *all* the output (`stdout` and `stderr`).

Maybe there is a simpler way to just get the output of a bash script which is started from python?

Comment: I've changed your `'. testbash.sh'` to `./testbash.sh` and tested on Python3, it works. Hope you first clarify the Python version and try to fix the command issue.

Comment: When I try that I get an error `/bin/sh: ./testbash.sh: No such file or directory`!

Comment: so you are using python to launch a bash script to launch python scripts...? Doesn't seem like the best solution to me...

Comment: That is quite true. But for now this seems to be the only way (as the bash script runs on a cluster starting parallel python scripts  etc). For this question it does not matter. Could be any shell command that creates a multi line error message.

Answer (score 1):

To be run with python3

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os
import stat
import sys
import time
from subprocess import PIPE, Popen, STDOUT
from threading  import Thread
try:
    from queue import Queue, Empty
except ImportError:
    from Queue import Queue, Empty  # python 2.x
ON_POSIX = 'posix' in sys.builtin_module_names
TESTBASH = '/tmp/testbash.sh'
def create_bashtest():
    with open(TESTBASH, 'wt') as file_desc:
        file_desc.write("""#!/usr/bin/env bash
export MAX_SEED=2
echo "Start test"
pids=""
for seed in `seq 1 ${MAX_SEED}`
do
  python -c "raise ValueError('test')" &
  pids="${pids} $!"
  sleep .1 # Wait so that error messages don't get out of order.
done
wait $pids; return_code=$?
sleep 0.2 # Wait for background messages to be processed.
echo "pids: ${pids}"
echo "End test"
sleep 1 # Wait for main process to handle all the output
exit $return_code
""")
    os.chmod(TESTBASH, stat.S_IEXEC|stat.S_IRUSR|stat.S_IWUSR)

def enqueue_output(queue):
    pipe = Popen([TESTBASH], stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT,
                 bufsize=1, close_fds=ON_POSIX, shell=True)
    out = pipe.stdout
    while pipe.poll() is None:
        line = out.readline()
        if  line:
            queue.put(line.decode('ascii'))
        time.sleep(.1)
    print('returncode = {}'.format(pipe.returncode))

create_bashtest()
C_CHANNEL = Queue()

THREAD = Thread(target=enqueue_output, args=(C_CHANNEL,))
THREAD.daemon = True
THREAD.start()

while THREAD.is_alive():
    time.sleep(0.1)
    try:
        line = C_CHANNEL.get_nowait()
    except Empty:
        pass # print("no output")
    else:
        print(line, end='')
```

Hope this helps :

Answer (score 0):

First, looks like buffers are not being flushed.  Redirecting (and, to be safe, appending) stdout/stderr to a file(s) rather than to the terminal, may help.  You can always use `tee` (or `tee -a`) if you really want both.  Using context managers 'might' help.

As far as the zero return code, `$!`
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/386196/doesnt-work-on-command-line
`!` may be invoking history invoking history, thereby `$!` resulting in an empty value.

If you somehow end up with just a bare `wait` the return code will be a zero. Regardless, return codes can be tricky, and you might be picking a successful return code from elsewhere.

Take a look at stdbuf command to change the buffer sizes for stdout and stderr:
[Is there a way to flush stdout of a running process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546183/is-there-a-way-to-flush-stdout-of-a-running-process)
That may also help with getting the rest of your expected output.

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite the `while` block this way:

```py
# read line without blocking
while t.is_alive():
    try:
        line = q.get(block=False)
    except Empty:
        # print(line)
        pass
    else:
        # got line
        print(line, end='')
```

You don't want to block on getting a line from the `Queue` when there's none, and you don't need a timeout in this case, as it's only used when blocking the thread is required. Consequently, if the `Queue.get()` throws `Empty`, there's no line to print, and we just `pass`.

===

Also, let's clarify the script execution logic.

Since you're using Bash expressions, and the default shell used by `Popen` is `/bin/sh`, you'd probably want to rewrite the invokation line this way:

```py
p = Popen(['/usr/bin/bash','-c', './testbash.sh'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, bufsize=1, close_fds=ON_POSIX)
```

It won't hurt to add a shebang to your shell script, too:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash
<... rest of the script ...>
```

Comment: One last thing: sometimes the lines with `ValueError: test` get clobbered or superimposed, I couldn't figure out why this happens, but apparently this is a shell/pipe issue, and has nothing to do with your Python code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for these lines:

```sh
[1]-  Exit 1                  python -c "raise ValueError('test')"
[2]+  Exit 1                  python -c "raise ValueError('test')"
```

This is a function of the bash shell that's typically only available in `interactive` mode, i.e. when you're typing commands into a terminal. If you check the [bash source code](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/jobs.c#n3022), you can see that it [explicitly checks](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/jobs.c#n3159) the mode before printing to stdout/stderr.

In the more recent versions of bash, you can't set this inside a script: see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/364618 . However, you can set this yourself when starting the script:

```py
p = Popen(['/bin/bash -i ./testbash.sh'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, bufsize=1, close_fds=ON_POSIX, shell=True)
```

I will note that this is only working for me on Python3 - Python2 is only getting part of the output. It isn't clear version of Python you're using, but considering Python2 is end of life now we should probably all be trying to switch to Python3.

As for the bash script, even with interactive mode set it seems you have to change how you `wait` to get that output:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
export MAX_SEED=2
echo "Start test"
pids=""

for seed in `seq 1 ${MAX_SEED}`
do
    python -c "raise ValueError('test')" &
    pids="${pids} $!"
done
echo "pids: ${pids}"
wait -n $pids
wait -n $pids
ret=$?
echo "End test"
exit $ret
```

Normal `wait` wasn't working for me (Ubuntu 18.04), but `wait -n` seemed to work - but as it only waits for the next job to complete, I had inconsistent output just calling it once. Calling `wait -n` for each job launched seems to do the trick, but the program flow should probably be refactored to loop over the wait the same number of times you spin up the job.

Also note that to change the return code of the script, Philippe's answer has the right approach - the `$?` variable has the return code of the latest command that failed, which you can then pass to `exit`. (Yet another difference in Python versions: Python2 is returning `127` while Python3 returns `1` for me.) If you need the return values for each job, one way might be to parse out the values in the interactive job exit lines.

Answer (score -1):

Just guessing - could it be that a line that starts with an empty character / space is not recognized as a line by your logic.

Maybe this indent is the issue. Another option is, that there is a tab or something like that and the ascii decode might fail.

Answer (score -1):

This is how I usually use subprocess:

```
import subprocess

with subprocess.Popen(["./test.sh"], shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE) as p:
    error = p.stderr.read().decode()
    std_out = p.stdout.read().decode()
    if std_out:
        print(std_out)
    if error:
        print("Error message: {}".format(error))
```

Here you decode and read both the stdout and the stderr. You get everything but not in the same order, I don't if that's an issue.

Comment: This piece of code is blocking. I need a non blocking code